# Working with autocad in c#

Tags: c#, autocad

Is there any way to insert one kind of image files such as *png* or *jpg* to a drawing, programmatically in c# by using `Autodesk.Autocad.Interop` and `Autodesk.Autocad.Interop.common` dlls?

I have tried `AcadDocument.Database.ModelSpace.InsertBlock()` but it works just with dwg files and returns the following error for images :

"Invalid File Header."

Comment: Use the [vendor's support channels](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/community).

Comment: @HansPassant,Thanks for your reply, but it does not allow me to download from my country.Is there any other way or any other url to download that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InsertBlock() is only for inserting block definitions.  Use AddRaster() to import an image via AutoCAD Interop libraries:

```
var imgPath = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg";
var imgScale = 2.0;
var imgRot = (Math.PI / 180) * 90;
var imgPoint = new double[] {1, 1, 0};

doc.ModelSpace.AddRaster(imgPath, imgPoint, imgScale, imgRot);
```

Where 'doc' is the ActiveDocument of a running AutoCAD session.

Comment: Thanks a lot,That was my answer.I have searched too many but i could not find anything.I have another little question yet! How can i find the position of a special attribute in a block?